# Bulk Append a prefix to all submitted urls

Tags: javascript, php

Have a page where user will input several urls in a text field, each on their own line
...

```
    http://urlone.com

    http://urltwo.com
```

...
I would like to append a url- specifically: https://proxyurl.ub.com?login=urlfromabove to each line and have it return this in a text field the user can copy and paste, one on each line. either php or javascript would be ideal. ie:
...

```
     https://proxyurl.ub.com?login=http://urlone.com

     https://proxyurl.ub.com?login=http://urlone.com
```

I have searched but cant find anything like this.

I have code to do one at a time:
...

```html
<script language="javascript">

<!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--

function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}

 
 function makeLink() { 
 var oin=document.frm.intext; 
 var oout=document.frm.outtext; 
 var intxt=oin.value; 
 if(intxt.length==0) { 
 oin.focus(); 
 alert("No URL entered!"); 
 } 
 
 else { 
 var prep="https://proxy.name.edu/login?url="; 
 var rc=intxt.indexOf('https://proxy.name.edu/login?url=') 
 var rd=intxt.indexOf('.proxy.libraries.uc.edu') 
 var wellFormedHttp=intxt.indexOf('http://') 
 var wellFormedHttps=intxt.indexOf('https://') 
 if(wellFormedHttp=='0'||wellFormedHttps=='0'){ 
 //alert("Matched http://"+wellFormed); 
 //} 
 if(rc==-1) { 
 if(rd==-1){ 
 oout.value=prep+intxt; 
 oout.focus(); 
 oout.select(); 
 } 
 else{ 
 alert("That is a translated EzProxy URL and shouldn't be used. Click OK to fix"); 
 intxt = intxt.replace(/.proxy.name.edu/g,"") 
 oout.value=prep+intxt; 
 oin.focus(); 
 oin.select(); 
 } 
 } 
 else { 
 alert("That is already an EzProxy prefixed URL, so no change is needed"); 
 oout.value=""; 
 oin.focus(); 
 oin.select(); 
 } 
 } 
 else{ 
 alert("The URL source URL doesn't start with http:// or https:// or contains multiple entries, please enter a valid URL like https://someaddress.com"); 
 oout.value=""; 
 oin.focus(); 
 oin.select(); 
 } 
 } 
 
 } 
 
//--><!]]>

</script>
 
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <hr>
    <form name="frm" id="frm">
1.<strong> Copy and paste your source URL here:</strong>
<p><textarea aria-label="Source URL" cols="60" name="intext" rows="5"></textarea><br />
 </p>
<p>2<strong>. Click the Create Link button:</strong>
  <input onclick="makeLink();" type="button" value="Create Link" class="btn">
  </p>
<p><br />
  3.<strong> Copy, use, and share this result link:</strong><br>
  
</p>
<p><textarea aria-label="Resulting Link" cols="60" name="outtext" rows="5"  id="myInput"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
 
  <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Copy link to Clipboard</button> <i>(Click this button to copy the url to your clipboard)</i>
<br></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>  <br />
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" />
</p>
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>

</form>
```

...

Comment: whats your current code? either php or javascript code

Comment: Can you use `var_dump()` for the url input on the server side after submitting the form and update your question with it? We need to see how that data is actually formatted

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton additionally what is the code that is generating the url , javascript or php as stated

Comment: javascript is current method.